# Filter on object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

in an Angular project I'm trying to delete an object from an array, to do this in need to filter the array and then replace that array into the storage (in this case capacitor/storage)

my function:

```
deleteArticle(id: string): void {
this.order = this.order[0].filter(p => p.products.productKey !== id);
```

}

order: Order; ==>

```
export interface OrderProduct {
  productKey: string;
  productName: string;
  price: number;
}
export interface Order {
  key?: string;
  customerKey: string;
  products: OrderProduct[];
  country?: string;
  city?: string;
  postcode?: string;
  addressLine?: string;
  creationDate?: any; //date
}
```

in HTML the on click:

```
<ion-col>
    <ion-button (click)="deleteArticle(p.productKey)">
      <ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-col>
```

When clicking on the button, I can see the array is like expect it to be, same as the ID where I want to filter on, but I keep on getting this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

[image: image of console showing error]

Comment: Whenever you get "Cannot read properties of undefined" it's happening because the object you're reading properties/methods on is undefined. In this case `this.order[0]` *at the time the code is trying to read it*. Your log is read long after that code has run. This is likely due to asynchronicity.

Comment: unfortunatly, i turned it into an async function to give it time to load but i'm having the same error

Answer (score 0):

If order is of type Order as you write  and you try `this.order[0].filter...` you try to access a property named '0' (as in 'zero') of this.order, which most likely is undefined and thus has no filter method. from what I see you can remove the '[0]' and it could work. without more code just a guess tho.

Comment: when removing the [0], its complaining 'TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Order'.'

Answer (score 0):

i've found the solution, it was a data type thing :)

needed to add products to this.order...

```
async deleteArticle(id: string): Promise<void> {
    this.order.products = this.order.products.filter(p => p.productKey !== id);
  }
```